# shell script to login as root into one server without password prompt

Tags: shell

I have a shell script in which i have to login as root into one particular server(server123)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'root123' | ssh -t root@server1
```

but this line is asking to enter password in password prompt.
How can i avoid entering the password
i dont want to change the sudeors file

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to setup [ssh keys](https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh).